# Работа с checkbox Angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Имеем список (чекбокс), как сделать еще 1 отдельный список и форму динамического поиска к нему(не получается чего-то) вот мой пример

```js
      var app = angular.module('app', []);
app.controller('appCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.country = [
                    { 'name': 'Австрия', 'desc': 'Австрия', 'check': true },
                    { 'name': 'Азербайджан', 'desc': 'Азербайджан',  'check': false  },
                    { 'name': 'Албания', 'desc': 'Албания',  'check': true  }
                    ];
});
```

```html
       <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div class="container" ng-app="app" ng-controller="appCtrl">
  <input ng-model="query">
  <ul>
    <li ng-repeat="item in country | filter:query">
      <label>
      <input name="country" type="checkbox" ng-model="item.check"  ng-checked="{{item.check}}" value="{{item.desc}}" >{{item.desc}}</label>
          
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Нужно на 1 странице сделать еще 1 такую форму поиска

Comment: я не понял вопроса. Нужно чтобы было два подобных списка на странице? У каждого свой поиск или этот не работает?

Comment: да 2 списка с двумя различными строками поиска на одной странице по своему списку!(этот для 1 страницы для 2-ух косяк не подргружает контроллер)

Comment: по моему разумению нужно создать директиву, которая будет использовать этот контроллер, и тогда можно вставлять где угодно этот список.

Comment: если не трудно сделайте пример

Answer (score 1):

Что-то в это роде:

```js
var app = angular.module('app', []);

    app.directive('myList', function () {
        return {
            restrict: 'E',
            require: 'ngModel',
             scope: {},
            template: function (el, attr) {

                return '<input type="text" ng-model="' + attr.ngModel + '">' +
                        '<ul>' +
                        '<li ng-repeat="item in country | filter:' + attr.ngModel + '">' +
                        '<label>' +
                        '<input name="country" type="checkbox" ng-model="item.check" ng-checked="{{item.check}}" value="{{item.desc}}">{{item.desc}}</label>' +
                        '</li>' +
                        '</ul>';
            },
            controller: function ($scope) {
                $scope.country = [
                    {'name': 'Австрия', 'desc': 'Австрия', 'check': true},
                    {'name': 'Азербайджан', 'desc': 'Азербайджан', 'check': false},
                    {'name': 'Албания', 'desc': 'Албания', 'check': true}
                ];
            },
            link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
                element.removeAttr('ng-model');
            }
        };
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div class="container" ng-app="app">

    <my-list ng-model="query"></my-list>
    <my-list ng-model="query1"></my-list>
    <my-list ng-model="query2"></my-list>
</div>
```

Comment: в вашем примере список общий я имел ввиду : "да 2 списка с двумя различными строками поиска на одной странице по своему списку"

Comment: строки поиска различные, список тот же. Каждая строка поиска отвечает за список под ней. Т.е. если я ввожу в одном поле, не изменяются все списки одновременно. Либо я чего-то не понимаю в задании.

Comment: Каждая строка за разный список должны отвечать, и у вас если выбиру галочку она везде поставиться

Comment: Упс, забыл изолировать scope :)